# Laravel eloquent model not following table naming convention

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, naming-conventions

I'm trying to run this code:

```
$media = Media::first();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'reshi.media' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `media` limit 1)

It seems that this specific model is not following the name convention for tables. I didn't set the `$table` property on this model. That's how it looks like:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model {

    public function tags()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Reshi\Tag');
    }

    public function posts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Laravel understand `Media` as plural for `Medium`. Thus, he doesn't try to fetch from table `medias`.

Check:
[Issue - GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8673#issuecomment-100444021)

Comment: Thanks! just loosing a couple hours trying to figure out why my "Equipment" model was not  working. :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is following your name spacing as part of the convention.

Just do this - and it will work:

```
class Media extends Model {

    protected $table = 'media';

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the thing is I have a few other models without `$table` property in the same namespace and they work just fine.  For example, I can do `Tag::first();` and it will work. I know I can set the table name properly using the `$table` property, but why is this happening?

Comment: Is your namespace `app`? Can you post the full model with the namespace and everything?

Comment: Just did. Still not working. The funny thing is that all other models still working.

Comment: Got my answer on github, check my answer if you want to figure it out.